# How to show that $x^{1/n}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq 2$. For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, we have
$$(x-y)=(x^{1/n}-y^{1/n})\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x^{1/n})^{n-i-1}(y^{1/n})^{i},$$
which can be equivalently stated as
$$\frac{x-y}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x^{1/n})^{n-i-1}(y^{1/n})^{i}}=x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}.$$
For $\varepsilon>0$, why is it enough to take $|x-y|<\varepsilon^n$? This will only work if $$\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x^{1/n})^{n-i-1}(y^{1/n})^{i}}\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{n-1}},$$
but why would this hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \ge y$ and $\eta_n := x^{1/n} - y^{1/n}$. Then $\eta_n \ge 0$ and $$x = (y^{1/n} + \eta_n)^n \ge (y^{1/n})^n + \eta_n^n = y + \eta_n^n$$ Thus $0 \le \eta_n \le (x - y)^{1/n}$. By symmetry it follows that $|x^{1/n} - y^{1/n}| \le |x - y|^{1/n}$. Therefore, if $|x - y| < \epsilon^n$ then $|x^{1/n} - y^{1/n}| < (\epsilon^n)^{1/n} = \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the general form of the first inequality that you used? I mean what is theorem?

Comment: @guam apply the binomial theorem and note that all the terms are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the rate of increase is the fastest at $x_0=0$, and in that case you have $|f(x)-f(0)|=x^{1/n}<\epsilon$ if $x<\epsilon^n$. So what you want to show is that $|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq |f(h)-f(0)|$ if $x>0$ and $h>0$. This ultimately follows from the fact that the function is concave down.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would be the optimal modulus of continuity here?

Comment: @guam There isn't an especially nice expression for it, but one option is $\delta(\epsilon,x)=\max \left \{ \epsilon^n,n \epsilon x^{1-1/n} \right \}$. If you don't like the dependence on $x$ then you can pick an $x_0$ and replace $x$ with that.

Comment: @guam Actually what I said is not correct; the best *uniform* modulus of continuity there is is in fact $\epsilon^n$, since $|\delta^{1/n}-0|>\epsilon$ if $\delta>\epsilon^{1/n}$. What I was trying to say is that the regularity deteriorates a lot as you get near zero, but in this context that's a bit misleading to say, so I will remove that sentence.

Comment: Got it thank you